# Xcode 12.3 is not responding a few seconds after opening it

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update, performance

I updated to Xcode 12.3 on my MacBook Pro 2018 13" yesterday and face a strange problem right now.

**Problem:** Every time I open up Xcode, it will first work fine. However, after a few actions / seconds, the screen freezes and the circle loading indicator is displayed. The app does not respond anymore and I have to force close it.

**More Information:**

- The freezing is Xcode specific. I can use all other Programs while Xcode is frozen and the circle is spinning. It doesn't seem like a resource problem.
- This not only happens with existing projects. I created a new one and encountered the same Problem.
- I alredy reinstalled Xcode, but that does not solve the problem.
- I already deleted the `~/Library/Developer` Folder *(like a few other posts recommended)* and installed the components on Xcode start again. Still the same problem.

**Has anyone an idea on how to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a recently reported bug with Xcode 12.3. I am not aware of any response from Apple yet, but you might be able to fix this issue by turning off the over-the-air test device builds.

- Top Menu: Window > Devices & Simulators
- Uncheck "Connect via Network" for each physical device

I recommend [filing bugs with Apple](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) and watching the [forum thread about this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669378?login=true).

You also [revert to Xcode 12.2](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

Comment: FWIW the "Connect via Network" fix didn't work for me. I had no devices listed, and even when I connected my iPhone via cable, the option was deselected 

Comment: Removing network connected devices and restarting seemed to fix the issue for me a while, and then after running on a USB-connected iPhone the same issue came back up, even after disconnecting from the device.

Comment: this surprisingly worked on my M1 Macbook Air